# lavalink not working when making discord bot with DSharpPlus. not throwing any errors

Tags: c#, discord

command class, no errors when running

```
using DSharpPlus;
using DSharpPlus.CommandsNext;
using DSharpPlus.CommandsNext.Attributes;
using DSharpPlus.Entities;
using DSharpPlus.Lavalink;

namespace MusicBot
{
    public class MediaCommands : BaseCommandModule
    {

        [Command("join"), Description("joins user voice channel")]
        public async Task JoinVC(CommandContext ctx, DiscordChannel chn)
        {
            var lava = ctx.Client.GetLavalink();
            if (!lava.ConnectedNodes.Any())
            {
                await ctx.RespondAsync("The Lavalink connection is not established");
                return;
            }
            var node = lava.ConnectedNodes.Values.First();
            if (chn.Type != ChannelType.Voice)
            {
                await ctx.RespondAsync("Not a valid voice channel");
                return;
            }
            await node.ConnectAsync(chn);
            await ctx.RespondAsync($"Joined {chn}");
        }
```

program class no error when running

```
using System;
using DSharpPlus;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using DSharpPlus.CommandsNext;
using DSharpPlus.Lavalink;
using DSharpPlus.Net;
using LortBasic;
using LortMusic;

namespace Lort
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            var LortBot = new DiscordClient(new DiscordConfiguration()
            {
                Token = "mytoken",
                TokenType = TokenType.Bot,
                Intents = DiscordIntents.All,
                MinimumLogLevel = LogLevel.Debug
            });
            
            //lavalink

            var endpoint = new ConnectionEndpoint
            {
                Hostname = "127.0.0.1",
                Port = 25565
            };

            var lavalinkconfig = new LavalinkConfiguration
            {
                Password = "youshallnotpass",
                RestEndpoint = endpoint,
                SocketEndpoint = endpoint,
            };

            var lavalink = LortBot.UseLavalink();
            await LortBot.ConnectAsync();
            await lavalink.ConnectAsync(lavalinkconfig);

            await Task.Delay(-1);
```

I'm following this guide to make a discord bot with c# using DSharpPlus https://dsharpplus.github.io/articles/audio/lavalink/setup.html and everything works up until trying to get the bot to join a voice channel. it has admin rights and no errors in lavalink console, bot console, vs, none anywhere.  nothing happens though... at all